# Laravel using regular expression for exclude routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

in `VerifyCsrfToken` class i want to use for example

```
protected $except = [
    '/dashboard/administrator/attachImage',
    '/{ANY}/product/payment/checkTransaction'
];
```

instead of:

```
protected $except = [
    '/dashboard/administrator/attachImage',
    '/fa/product/payment/checkTransaction',
    '/en/product/payment/checkTransaction',
    '/ru/product/payment/checkTransaction',
    '/az/product/payment/checkTransaction',
];
```

how can i use that and my question is laravel cab be support using regular expression on this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a regular expression, but since Laravel uses request's `is()` method under the hood, you can use asterisk like this:

```
protected $except = [
    '/dashboard/administrator/attachImage',
    '/*/product/payment/checkTransaction',
];
```